# How can I set a standard linter,formatter and settings for a project and save those to the git repo?

Tags: python, git, formatter, linter

I want others who clone the repo to have these settings, right now I have a `settings/.vscode` file with these settings

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "*/__pycache__": true,
        "*/*/__pycache__": true,
        ".mypy_cache": true,
        ...
    },
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 100,
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "autopep8",
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
}
```

I don't want to save these settings to the common repo

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
"python.formatting.autopep8Path": "autopep8",
"files.exclude": {
    "*/__pycache__": true,
    "*/*/__pycache__": true,
    ".mypy_cache": true,
    ...
},
```

but everything else I would

---

I found that I could create a `.editorconfig`, but ccould find how to set linters and formatters in it. I could only really find 2 settings that I want, and couldn't really find other settings

```
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
max-line-length = 100
```

Comment: The "how to set the settings" part is up to the software you're setting. The "how to save to the Git repository" is simple enough: you can do this if and only if you can put the settings in a file in the working tree. If so, do that. If not, you can't do it (well, not like this at least—you could still save a file, but you'll have to manually install the file wherever it might need to be installed).

Comment: In general, for formatting Python, I like [black](https://github.com/psf/black). It cooperates well with Git: just put the control file at the top level of the repository. Whether you can get VSCode to *use* black, I have no idea.

Comment: @torek This is not an option for all the settings. So I need a way to set it for only some settings

Comment: @torek It has to be flake8 and mypy

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do in this case is to set whatever settings you can in an `.editorconfig` file, and then choose your linters and commit their configuration files to the repository, usually at the top level.  How to configure them, where to place their configuration files, and how to invoke them in an appropriate way is really dependent on the tools you're using.  If it's not clear, you can provide a script to invoke the linter in the proper way for your project.  Then, document which linters you're using, if your language has more than one obvious choice, and set up CI to run them automatically on your repository.

Note that `.editorconfig` files don't specify most formatting options.  They are useful for specifying the most common options that people use when writing code, such as indent size, tabs vs. spaces, line length, and line ending, but will not take the place of a good linter or formatting tool which is specific to your language.

In general, though, you want to avoid committing editor-specific files to the repository.  Just because *you* use VS Code does not mean *everybody* uses VS Code, and your VS Code settings will be completely useless to someone using a different editor, like Vim or Emacs.  In addition, many times editor-specific configuration files contain options which are not code style-specific, and other users of VS Code may not care for your particular settings.

If you have files that are build products or cache files you don't want to check into the repository, those should go into your `.gitignore` file in the repository.  That will prevent all Git users from checking them in.  If you have files that are specific to your editor (e.g., backup files or swap files), configure those in the file you specify with Git's `core.excludesfile` option.